# Cubic numbers that can be divided by $2^{26} \cdot 3^{16} \cdot 5^8 \cdot 7^4$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-theorem

There's another set of exercises given by my teacher to work on. My subject is permutation and combinatorics.

The question is as follows:

> Which cubic numbers are there that can divide into the number $$2^{26} \cdot 3^{16} \cdot 5^8 \cdot 7^4?$$

I just need the idea of what to search for. Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the prime factorization of a cubic number?

Comment: So I have to list every single one with the prime factorization?

Comment: Try looking at the prime factorizations of some cubic numbers and see if you notice any patterns.

Comment: For example, 2^26
That there are about 8 of 2^3 in the factorization

Comment: The idea is you need the numbers in the form $2^{3a}\cdot3^{3b}\cdot5^{3c}\cdot7^{3d}$, $0\le 3a \le 26$, $0\le 3b \le 16$, $0\le 3c \le 8$, $0\le 3d \le 4$. So there are $9$ possible $a$s, $6$ possible $b$s, $3$ -- $c$s and $2$ -- $d$s _independently_, thus giving $9\cdot 6\cdot 3 \cdot 2$ positive cubic divisors overall.

Comment: Ah i get it, so to list on 2^26
I can write possibilities such as 2^3, 4^3, 8^3, 16^3, 32^3, 64^3.
Is there any faster way to list every single possibilities?

Comment: I think I found it. If I were to add up the results of these
1. 8x5x2x1
2. 8x5x2
3. 8x5x1
4. 5x2x1
...
up until 16, which stands alone, and sum it up with 1^3
I will get 324 numbers.
Is that correct?

Comment: It seems like this would make more sense if you are asking for which cubic numbers divide into $2^{26} \cdot 3^{16} \cdot 5^8 \cdot 7^4$. That seems to be the question commenters and the accepted answer are responding to. But as written, it's backwards. It's asking how many cubic numbers can be divided into by $2^{26} \cdot 3^{16} \cdot 5^8 \cdot 7^4$. And there are of course infinitely many of those.

Comment: @alex changed that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of choices $(a,b,c,d)$ that satisfy the inequalities in @Alexey's hint is:
$$\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{26}{3}\right\rfloor\right)\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{16}{3}\right\rfloor\right)\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{8}{3}\right\rfloor\right)\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{4}{3}\right\rfloor\right)=(9)(6)(3)(2)=324$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that the OP should re-interpret the query into three separate questions, as follows:

Let $n = 2^{(26)} \;\times\; 3^{(16)} \;\times\; 5^8 \;\times\; 7^4.$

(1)
Using the prime factorization theorem, what are all the possible factors of $n$?

(2)
Of these factors, which ones will be *perfect cubes*?

(3)
How many such *perfect cubes* are there?

Answers:

(1)
Numbers of the form 
$\left(2^a \;\times\; 3^b \;\times\; 5^c \;\times\;7^d\right),\;$ where 
$a,b,c,d$ are all integers and 
$0 \leq a \leq 26$ and 
$0 \leq b \leq 16$ and 
$0 \leq c \leq 8$ and 
$0 \leq d \leq 4$.

(2)
$n$ will be a *perfect cube* if and only if 
each of $a,b,c,d$ is a multiple of 3.

(3)
There are 9 choices for $a$, 6 choices for $b$, 3 choices for $c$, and 2 choices for $d$.

These choices are **independent of each other.**
Therefore, the # of such *satisfying perfect cubes* is 
$9 \times  6 \times 3 \times 2 = 324.$